# where are the euw servers located for league of legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

my ping recently went up from its average and I want to check if it is my lol or Internet that is lagging. Which is why I would like to know where the EUW servers are located so that I can do a ping test using speedtest.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LoL servers moved to Amsteradam a few months ago.

http://forums.euw.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1764406